# How to solve this error : No overload for 'node_changed' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: asp.net

How to solve this error : No overload for 'node_changed' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

hi, i have done treeview in asp.net.

+football.

here + is having one property called `"OnTreeNodePopulate"` and Football contains property called `"OnSelectedNodeChanged"`.

i designed in aspx page like follows:

so, when i click + it invokes in aspx.cs page like follows:

```
   protected void Pluspopulate_clicked(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs  e )
    {
        session["aaa"]=e.node // here i can get current node
        //here i am passing two argument to populateSublevel method ie id and current node.
        PopulateSubLevel(Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.Value),' " + session["aaa"] + " ');

    }
```

Till now fine. but when click on football, it invokes following aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Node_changed(object sender, Eventargs  e )
{
     //here  also i want to pass two argument to populateSublevel method ie id and current node. like what i get in pluspopulate_cliked event.

     // But here i am not able to get current node. here i need to get current node.    

     session["aaa"]=e.node // i need like this. but here i am not able get current node


 }
```

so when i give TreeNoeEventArgs e in Node_changed, it throws an error like " No overload for 'node_changed' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'"

how to solve this . how to can i get current node in node_chaged event. Please help me!.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeView.SelectedNodeChanged` Event method has two arugments, object sender and Eventargs  e. You can learn at [TreeView.SelectedNodeChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged.aspx).

Here's how you can use it:

```
protected void Node_changed(object sender, Eventargs  e )
{
     //Assuming that your treeview id is TreeView1 
     TreeNode myNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode; // This is the current node you need.
     session["aaa"]= myNode;
}
```